# Redirect non-www to www. equivalent but allow one REQUEST_URI regex match?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+?games/.+?\.jpg$ [NC] #if does not match then proceed with redirect...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.+?games/(.+?)\.jpg$ index.php?g=$1 [L] #will only get to this point if not starting with www.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Above code does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your use of `REQUEST_URI` variable that changes to `/index.php` due to your last rule and when `mod_rewrite` runs again your first rule happily adds `www` in the URL.

You should use `THE_REQUEST` variable, `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser **and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !games/.+?\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.+?games/(.+?)\.jpg$ index.php?g=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```